# Creating a temp .htm file in PHP and send it to the user?

Tags: php, symfony

Is there a simple way to create an empty temp .htm file on the server and send it to the user as download? I don't need to really create the file with fopen(), it's enough to just create it temporarily and send it to the user.

I need that for a website authentication. I found there is tmpfile() function within PHP, but it doesn't quite work for me yet. I am working on a Symfony project, maybe there are also a header function I don't know of.

All I need is:

```
$token = '12345';
$filename = $token . '.htm';
createatmpfile($filename);
header(send .htm file as download to the user);
```

Not sure how that works, but maybe my pseudocode above explains what I am looking for ..

**EDITED:**

That's how it works for Symfony2 (thanks Grad):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

Controller method:

```
public function generateAction() {
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$token.'.htm"'); 
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain PHP you could use to following line to force the user to download the response

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.htm"');
```

In Symfony you can use:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="filename.htm"');
```

With this header set you can either just execute your controller (and let the view fill in the response), or use `$contents = file_get_contents($path)` together with `return $this->renderText($contents)`.

But depending on what you're trying to achieve: you don't have to create a tempfile to force the to download it.

Comment: Grad, can you help me? I am actually working on Symfony2, $this->getResponse() throughs me a fatal error (call to undefined method). I read that I can use new Response(); in combination to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; namespace.

Comment: $response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$token.'.htm"');
return $response; works!! Thanks Grad